# Is it safe to rely on the order of null values in an order by?

Tags: java, database, oracle, null, sql-order-by

I've just come across this code, which to me seems a little fragile:

```
String statement = "select * from SOURCE where category = ? order by sub_category desc";
...
List<Source> results = query.list();

/* If we get more than one result return the one with the null sub-category 
 (the 'order by' should make the first record the one with the null): */
if(results.size() > 0) {
    return results.get(0);
}else{
    return null;
}
```

I'm going to refactor it anyway, but my curiosity has been ignited!

Is it safe to rely on the ordering of nulls in an order by clause?  Is the ordering database specific or is there a vendor independent consensus?

Comment: With Oracle, you can specify `order by sub_category desc NULLS LAST` or `NULLS FIRST`.. `NULL`s would be in the _last_ for _ASC_ and _first_ in _DESC_ by default.

Comment: See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html and look for `nullsAreSortedAtEnd()`, `nullsAreSortedAtStart()`, `nullsAreSortedHigh()` and `nullsAreSortedLow()`; if you have luck, one of these will return `true`…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ordering of null values is database specific. Say, MSSQL considers nulls as 'less than any other value', so nulls would be first in sorting ASC and last if sorting DESC. Oracle by default considers nulls as 'greater than any other value', but it has special syntax, ORDER BY column ASC|DESC NULLS FIRST|LAST, so developer can explicitly put nulls into required position. And so on.